# I'm trying to re-render my pug template through setInterval(). Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I'm trying to re-render my pug template through setInterval().

I'm trying to have a page display live data from a MySQL server. I can get the data to the page but I don't know how to update the data shown without refreshing the entire page.

I've attempted to implement AJAX and also tried to do this via socket.io but failed to send the data to the pug template on both attempts.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var pug = require('pug');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var clients = [];
var outsideData = require('./public/data.js');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.pug', {
        data: outsideData.getData()
    });
});

io.sockets.on('connect', function() {
    clients.push(io.sockets);
    console.log("connected");
});

//Recompile Pug Template
function recompile() {
    var pug = require('pug');
    var template = require('fs').readFileSync('./views/index.pug', 'utf8');
    var pugFn = pug.compile(template, {
        filename: './views/index.pug',
        pretty: true
    });
    var renderedTemplate = pugFn({
        data: outsideData.getData()
    });
}

//Send data every second.
setInterval(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        recompile();
        clients[i].emit('data', outsideData.getData());
    }
}, 30000);

//Handle diconnected clients.
io.sockets.on('disconnect', function() {
    var index = clients.indexOf(io.socket);
    if (index != -1) {
        clients.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

server.listen(3001);
```

index.pug

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Socket Communication
         script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js')
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        //script(src="client.js")
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            var myData = $('myData');
            console.log(data)
        });
    body
        h1= "Help me..."
        p= JSON.stringify(data)
```

Update:
Here are the changes that works. Thank you mk12ok.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var pug = require('pug');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var clients = [];
var outsideData = require('./public/data.js');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.pug');
});

io.sockets.on('connect', function() {
    clients.push(io.sockets);
    console.log("connected");
});

//Send data every second.
setInterval(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        clients[i].emit('data', outsideData.getData());
    }
}, 1000);

//Handle diconnected clients.
io.sockets.on('disconnect', function() {
    var index = clients.indexOf(io.socket);
    if (index != -1) {
        clients.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

server.listen(3001);
```

index.pug

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Socket Communication
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        //script(src="client.js")
    body
        h1= "Help me..."
        p(id="data")
        script.
            var socket = io.connect();
            socket.on('data', function(data) {
                //Replace JSON.stringify(data) with JSON.stringify(data.tag) to retrieve a specific value stored in your JSON data.
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Received" +    JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(data)
            });
```

Comment: You don't have to update `index.pug` but rather update the page with the data sent to the client through `socket.io`

Comment: By updating the page do you mean I update index.pug? I don't quite understand what to do with the data that is coming in on the page via socket.on() the console.log(data) prints it fine but I don't know how to pass that data into a pug variable. p= data

Comment: I mean you can update the page with DOM manipulation with plain javascript or jquery. As far as I understand you will send arrays with the results of mysql queries. You can easily show the data on the page in several ways. Please show the html code of your page and we can work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of re-rendering the pug file you can try this:

your server (very much the same code):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const pug = require('pug');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.pug');
});

setInterval(function() {
    io.emit('data', 'random number: ' + Math.random().toString());
}, 1000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected');       
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });  
});

http.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

and an example of `index.pug`:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Testing socket.io
  body
    h1 Testing socket.io
    br
    h3(id="status") not connected 
    br
    p(id="data") 
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script.
      var socket = io();

      socket.on('connect', function() {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "connected";   
      });

      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Received " + data;
      });
```